# Join two multidimensional arrays by matching elements on similar columns javascript es6

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, es6-promise

I am working in Google sheets running `chrome V8`

I have two arrays made from range data on two different sheets

in a real-life situation, I do know in advance the width or length of arr1 or arr2.  All I know is they are not the same dimensions

Both arrays have an `Id` column. arr1 will always have the `Id` column as the first column.  I do not know in advance the column position of the `Id` column in arr2

arr1 if printed to a sheet would look like

```
Id  |Label  |SAH1   |SAH2    |SAH3
---------------------------------------
aa1 |Bob    |stuff1 |stuff10 |stuff19
aa2 |Eggbert|stuff2 |stuff11 |stuff20
aa3 |Juan   |stuff3 |stuff12 |stuff21
aa4 |Alice  |stuff4 |stuff13 |stuff22
aa5 |Fraya  |stuff5 |stuff14 |stuff23
aa6 |Ted    |stuff6 |stuff15 |stuff24
aa7 |Velma  |stuff7 |stuff16 |stuff25
aa8 |Carol  |stuff8 |stuff17 |stuff26
aa9 |LeRoy  |stuff9 |stuff18 |stuff27
```

arr2 if printed to a sheet would look like

```
Name             |SXH1      |Id     |SXH2
--------------------------------------------
Maya Townsend    |thing1    |mm1    |thing20
David Collste    |thing2    |mm2    |thing21
Bob              |thing3    |aa1    |thing22
Jennifer Menke   |thing4    |mm4    |thing23
Aissata Camara   |thing5    |mm5    |thing24
Marta Arranz     |thing6    |mm6    |thing25
Michael  Lennon  |thing7    |mm7    |thing26
Jonny Norton     |thing8    |mm8    |thing27
Carol            |thing9    |aa8    |thing28
Ted              |thing10   |aa6    |thing29
Katie Boone      |thing11   |mm11   |thing30
Adeline Sibanda  |thing12   |mm12   |thing31
Brian Blankinship|thing13   |mm13   |thing32
Christine Lai    |thing14   |mm14   |thing33
Jennifer Pierce  |thing15   |mm15   |thing34
Federico Bellone |thing16   |mm16   |thing35
Jeffrey Su       |thing17   |mm17   |thing36
Alice            |thing18   |aa4    |thing37
Sarah Ditton     |thing19   |mm19   |thing38
```

result arr if printed to a sheet needs to look like

```
Id  |Label  |SAH1   |SAH2    |SAH3    |Name |SXH1   |SXH2  
------------------------------------------------------------
aa1 |Bob    |stuff1 |stuff10 |stuff19 |Bob  |thing3 |thing22 
aa2 |Eggbert|stuff2 |stuff11 |stuff20 |""   |""     |""
aa3 |Juan   |stuff3 |stuff12 |stuff21 |""   |""     |""
aa4 |Alice  |stuff4 |stuff13 |stuff22 |Alice|thing18|thing37
aa5 |Fraya  |stuff5 |stuff14 |stuff23 |""   |""     |""
aa6 |Ted    |stuff6 |stuff15 |stuff24 |Ted  |thing10|thing29
aa7 |Velma  |stuff7 |stuff16 |stuff25 |""   |""     |""
aa8 |Carol  |stuff8 |stuff17 |stuff26 |Carol|thing9 |thing28
aa9 |LeRoy  |stuff9 |stuff18 |stuff27 |""   |""     |""
```

I have searched for a method to do this and could find nothing that I had the skill to alter

Here is a Google sheet with test data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0CFUEdpZ77IgKGVYXUinepg7we2F0311U4D5fAP17Y/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: "*I could find nothing that I had the skill to alter*" - so you expect us to present a solution? Please remember that StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please first try working on your skill, attempt to find a solution yourself, and when you have a concrete programming question in the course of that, then we can help you with it.

Comment: If you do not know the position of the "id" in `arr2`, how can you associate the value to the correct "column"? For example, how do you know which value in `arr2[0]` corresponds to the "SXH1"? Furthermore,could you confirm what type of relation (e.g. one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many) exists between `arr1` and `arr2`, please?

Comment: What do you plan to do with Rows whose ids don’t match

Comment: @Cooper I need those appended rows values to be blank, only the matched Ids will have appended values.  Did I answer your question?

Comment: That’s not that difficult of a problem you should try it yourself and come back when you have problems.

Comment: Does the "name" column in ````arr2```` need to have unique values as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to achieve the conversion `result arr` from `arr1` and `arr2` in your question using Google Apps Script.
- You don't know the column of `Id` in `arr2` sheet.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve values from 2 source sheets.
2. Create an object from the values of "arr2" sheet using the values of "Id".
3. Create an array for putting to the result sheet using the values of "arr1" and "arr2" sheets.
4. Put values to the result sheet to "Result" sheet.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please set each sheet name.

```
function myFunction() {
  const arr1SheetName = "arr1";
  const arr2SheetName = "arr2";
  const resultSheetName = "Result";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // 1. Retrieve values from 2 source sheets.
  const [[header1, ...values1], [header2, ...values2]] = [arr1SheetName, arr2SheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s).getDataRange().getValues());

  // 2. Create an object from the values of "arr2" sheet using the values of "Id".
  const indexId = header2.indexOf("Id");
  const obj = values2.reduce((o, r) => {
    const id = r[indexId];
    r.splice(indexId, 1);
    return Object.assign(o, {[id]: r});
  }, {});

  // 3. Create an array for putting to the result sheet using the values of "arr1" and "arr2" sheets.
  const array = values1.map(r => obj[r[0]] ? r.concat(obj[r[0]]) : r.concat(Array(3).fill("")));
  header2.splice(indexId, 1);
  array.unshift([...header1, ...header2]);
  
  // 4. Put values to the result sheet to "Result" sheet.
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(resultSheetName);
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

- In this case, from your shared Spreadsheet, the sheet names are `arr1`, `arr2` and `Result`. Please be careful this.
- And, in this script, even when the column of `Id` in `arr2` sheet is moved, the script works.

#### Result:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

From

- `arr1` sheet

  [image]
- `arr2` sheet

  [image]

To:

- `Result` sheet

  [image]

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you soo much, this works exactly as I needed. I look forward to studying your answer

Comment: Tanaike, in this part `Array(3).fill("")` what does the `(3)` mean?

Comment: @xyz333 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Array(3).fill("")`, it creates an array including 3 elements as `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Combine Matching Rows

```
function combineMatchingRows() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');//output sheet
  const vA1=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()-1,sh1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const hA1=sh1.getRange(1,1,1,sh1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  var hObj1={};//columns in sheet1
  hA1.forEach((h,i)=>{hObj1[h]=i+1;});
  const vA2=sh2.getRange(2,1,sh2.getLastRow()-1,sh2.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const hA2=sh2.getRange(1,1,1,sh2.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  var hObj2={};//columns in sheet2
  hA2.forEach((h,i)=>{hObj2[h]=i+1;});
  const id2A=sh2.getRange(2,hObj2['Id'],sh2.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().flat();//array of ids in sheet2
  var vO=[];
  vA1.forEach((r,i)=>{
    let idx=id2A.indexOf(r[hObj1['Id']-1]);
    if(idx!=-1) {
      vA2[idx].splice(hObj2['Id']-1,1);//remove second Id column
      var row=r.concat(vA2[idx]);
      vO.push(row);
    }
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,vO.length,vO[0].length).setValues(vO);
}
```

Sheet1:

```
Id,Label,SAH1,SAH2,SAH3
aa1,Bob,stuff1,stuff10,stuff19
aa2,Eggbert,stuff2,stuff11,stuff20
aa3,Juan,stuff3,stuff12,stuff21
aa4,Alice,stuff4,stuff13,stuff22
aa5,Fraya,stuff5,stuff14,stuff23
aa6,Ted,stuff6,stuff15,stuff24
aa7,Velma,stuff7,stuff16,stuff25
aa8,Carol,stuff8,stuff17,stuff26
aa9,LeRoy,stuff9,stuff18,stuff27
```

Sheet2:

```
Name,SXH1,Id,SXH2
Maya Townsend,thing1,mm1,thing20
David Collste,thing2,mm2,thing21
Bob,thing3,aa1,thing22
Jennifer Menke,thing4,mm4,thing23
Aissata Camara,thing5,mm5,thing24
Marta Arranz,thing6,mm6,thing25
Michael  Lennon,thing7,mm7,thing26
Jonny Norton,thing8,mm8,thing27
Carol,thing9,aa8,thing28
Ted,thing10,aa6,thing29
Katie Boone,thing11,mm11,thing30
Adeline Sibanda,thing12,mm12,thing31
Brian Blankinship,thing13,mm13,thing32
Christine Lai,thing14,mm14,thing33
Jennifer Pierce,thing15,mm15,thing34
Federico Bellone,thing16,mm16,thing35
Jeffrey Su,thing17,mm17,thing36
Alice,thing18,aa4,thing37
Sarah Ditton,thing19,mm19,thing38
```

Sheet3 (Output):

```
aa1,Bob,stuff1,stuff10,stuff19,Bob,thing3,thing22
aa4,Alice,stuff4,stuff13,stuff22,Alice,thing18,thing37
aa6,Ted,stuff6,stuff15,stuff24,Ted,thing10,thing29
aa8,Carol,stuff8,stuff17,stuff26,Carol,thing9,thing28
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help you gave